# jQuery blur should not fire if div is clicked/focused

Tags: jquery, input, blur

I have a standard text input that has a blur event.  The blur event should fire when anything in the document is clicked (other than the input AND `<div id='show-anyways'></div>`).

My problem is that I don't know how to add the `<div id='show-anyways'></div>` to negate the blur event function.

Hopefully I have explained myself well enough, I know it's kinda a weird situation.  Please let me know if you need more info.

Comment: show what you coded so far please.

Comment: You would need to either `e.preventDefault`, `e.stopPropagation`, or determine which was clicked and stop the bubbling before it hits the target. The design flaw I feel like is that you have a blur event handler on the DOM? Do I understand that right?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use the event target to determine what is clicked. Following will track all clicks on document and not trigger blur() if element is the DIV or the Input.

```
var $input=$( '#MY-Input-ID');

$(document).click(function(evt){
   var $tgt=$(evt.target);
   if( !$tgt.is( '#show-anyways') && !$tgt.is($input) ){
         $input.blur()
    }
})
```

It will not trigger on elements that have any preventPropogation set up.

Comment: I actually had to end up going with using $(document).click for my solution since the original input.blur event would not fire if the click/focus sequence was input -> #show-anyways -> document.click.  Therefore, the event between #show-anyways and document.click would not trigger the input.blur event...

Comment: Note: a good way to check for a click within a div and all of its children is to add `&& !$tgt.is($('*', $('#show-anyways')))` to the conditional statements within the click function above.

Comment: @garromark that only checks descendents of the element... `$tgt.closest('#show-anyways').length` will check descendents and the element.. not sure why I didn't use that one

Answer (score 1):

UPDATE: had to completely rewrite my solution. The `blur` event handler is attached to the event that loses focus: if it was similar to `mouseout` event, we could know which element will get the focus, but there's no such luck. So we have to resort capturing `.click` events instead - and trigger some function based on it, instead of listening to `blur` events.

```
var inputIsBlurred = function() { 
   console.log('Run away!!!');
};
$(document).click(function(e){
  var $target = $(e.target);
  console.log($target);
  if ($target.is('#some_input') // fired by an input - no special effects
      || $target.is('#show-anyways') // fired by 'show-anyways' div
      || $target.parents('#show-anyways').length > 0 // ... or its children
  ) {
      return true; // move along, nothing to do here
  }
  inputIsBlurred();
});​
```

Here's [a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bxfCB/1/) to play with. Sorry for that confusion caused by my original answer. (

Answer (score 1):

There are a few things missing from the other solutions. The most important is that you need to check if the input is focused before calling your blur event. The other thing is that a blur event is called not only if you click somewhere else: you can also call it when you go to another tab in your browser or if you hit `tab` or `shift + tab` to go to the next/previous input. Finally, you need to consider using the jQuery function [*closest()*](https://api.jquery.com/closest/) when you check if the target element is an exception of your blur event (it can be the child of your exception).

So, I came up with this jQuery prototype function:

```js
$.fn.extend({

    blurIfNot : function(options, handler)
    {
        var defaults =
        {
            except : [],
            maxParent : null // A DOM element within which
                             // a matching element may be found
        };
        var opt = $.extend({}, defaults, options);
        var time = new Date().getTime();
        
        this.each(function()
        {
            var thisInp = $(this);
            thisInp[0].blurIfNot = {};
            time += 1000000000000;
            
            var except = opt.except;
            
            if ($.isFunction(opt.except))
            { except = opt.except.call(thisInp[0]); }
            
            function fire_blur_event(_tar, evt, mousedown)
            {
                var proceed = true;
                
                for (var i in except)
                {
                    if (_tar.is(thisInp) ||
                    _tar.closest(except[i], opt.maxParent).length)
                    {
                        proceed = false;
                        break;
                    }
                }
                if (proceed)
                {
                    thisInp[0].blurIfNot.focus = false;
                    handler.call(thisInp[0], evt);
                }
                else if (mousedown)
                {
                    $('html').one('mouseup', function(e)
                    {
                        thisInp[0].focus();
                    });
                }
            }
            
            if (!thisInp[0].blurIfNot.isset)
            {
                $('html').mousedown(function(e)
                {
                    if (thisInp[0].blurIfNot.focus)
                    {
                        var tar = $(e.target);
                        
                        if (!tar.is('input'))
                        { fire_blur_event(tar, e, true); }
                    }
                });
                
                $(window).blur(function(e)
                {
                    if (thisInp[0].blurIfNot.focus)
                    {
                        thisInp[0].blurIfNot.focus = false;
                        handler.call(thisInp[0], e);
                    }
                });
            }
            else
            {   // to be able to update the input event if you have
                // created new inputs dynamically
                $('input').off('focus.blufIfNot' + time);
            }
            
            $('input').on('focus.blurIfNot' + time, function(e)
            {
                var tar = $(e.target);
                
                if (tar[0] == thisInp[0])
                { thisInp[0].blurIfNot.focus = true; }
                
                else if (thisInp[0].blurIfNot.focus)
                { fire_blur_event(tar, e); }
            });
            
            thisInp[0].blurIfNot.isset = true;
        });
        return this;
    }
});

$('#input_blur_if_not').blurIfNot(
{
    except : [
        $('.autocomplete'), $('.question')
    ],
    // You can also define the elements with a function:
    // except : function()
    // {
    //     return [ $(this).parent().find('.autocomplete') ];
    // },
    maxParent : $('#parent')[0] // optional
},
function(e)
{
    var rand = Math.random();
    
    $('#test').css('padding', rand * 100 + "px").
    html(rand + " blur !");
});
```

```css
.autocomplete {
    background: #eee;
}
.autocomplete, input {
    width: 200px;
    padding: 3px;
    border: 1px solid #555;
}
.question {
    display:inline-block;
    border-radius:50%;
    background:#137dba;
    color:#fff;
    font-weight:bold;
    padding:2px 7px;
    cursor:pointer;
}
#test {
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:260px;
    color:red;
    font-weight:bold;
    padding:10px 0;
    vertical-align:bottom;
}
```

```html
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>

<div id="parent">
    
    <input value="an input" />
    <br><br>
    <input id="input_blur_if_not" value="input with autocomplete menu" />
    
    <div class="question">?</div>
    <div class="autocomplete">
        <div>option 1</div>
        <div>option 2</div>
    </div>
    <br>
    <input value="another input" />
    <div id="test"></div>
  
</div>
```

Tested in Chrome and IE11. Feel free to comment if you need more explanation.

Comment: very comprehensive.  Thank you for taking the time to test and post this.

Answer (score 0):

could try adding some logic like?

```
$('input').blur(function(e){
var tester = e.target;
if ($(tester).attr('id') == 'show-anyways'){
return false;
}
else {
// do something?
}

});
```

this basically fires when the blur occurs, it checks what was clicked/targed and if it happens to be the show-anyways then it will return false and stop doing anything. but if its not show-anyways then it can do your blur event?

untested, but is this what you mean?

Comment: this is exactly what I mean, but e.target returns 'input' for me on the blur event...so I can't arrive at what your solution is...

Comment: found it - the construct in the event is originalEvent.explicitOriginalTarget

Comment: Sadly originalEvent.explicitOriginalTarget is Gecko only.

Comment: e.target will return the input, not the element you clicked. This solution won't work.

Answer (score 0):

Most answers look quiet complicated. You can simply do something like this:

```
$('selector').blur(function (e) {
        if (e.relatedTarget.tagName.toLowerCase() != 'element') {  // element = a, div and so on
          // do stuff here
        }
    })
```

The target of "blur" is the blurred object. The clicked element is relatedTarget - this is key. If the tagName is not enough you can check for things like id or class too.

Consider checking if e.relatedTarget is not null.