# jQuery blur except certain element

Tags: jquery, blur

I've set up a jsFiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/trevanhetzel/GzmrS/2/), code below.

I just have a textarea that gets a class added to it on focus and on blur it gets removed. The class makes the textarea extend by setting a height css attribute, so when you click the button to submit the form I don't want it to remove the class because it just seems awkward.

**HTML**

```
<div class="comment_display">
    <form>
        <textarea class="addcomment"></textarea>
        <input class="tagbtn" type="submit" value="Comment" />
    </form>            
</div>​
```

**CSS**

```
.addcommentOn {
    height: 100px;
}​
```

**Javascript**

```
// Lengthen the Discussion input on click
  $(function lengthenInput() {
    $(".addcomment").focus(function() {
        $(this).addClass("addcommentOn");
    });

    $(".addcomment").blur(function() {
        if ($("input.comment").data('clicked') != true) {
            $(this).removeClass("addcommentOn");
        }
    });
  });​
```

Comment: If the user blurs out of the field for any other reason (than to click the submit button), you still want to remove the class, yes?

Comment: Yes. The only reason the class should NOT be removed is if the user clicks the button.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Trying to fight with blur is not easy since it occurs prior to any mouse event on another element

Here's one concept that would need additional modification if you want the textarea to shrink when user leaves form. Replace `blur` handler with following:

```
$('form').on('click', function(evt) {
    var $tgt = $(evt.target);
     if ($tgt.is('input[type="submit"]') || $tgt.is('.addcommentOn')  ) {
          return;
      }else{
           $('.addcommentOn').not($tgt).removeClass("addcommentOn");
      }
})
```

EDIT: need to also modify `focus` handler a bit once more elements added to form:

```
 $(".addcomment").focus(function() {
    $('.addcommentOn').removeClass('addcommentOn');
    $(this).addClass("addcommentOn");

});
```

DEMO(updated): http://jsfiddle.net/GzmrS/38/

Comment: That works great! Definitely wouldn't have come up with that solution, but thank you very much for the help. I'm trying to go through it now and piece together *how* it works now. And also I changed 'form' to 'body' and it works just how I hoped it would.

Comment: ws going to suggest click on body also, likely will take care of most scenarios you would need to shrink the element

Answer (score 0):

Charlietfl's answer is good, but there are still two other ways a blur event can be called: if you go to another tab in your browser or if you hit `tab` to go to the next input. You can see my solution and code snippet here:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/32596535/1895428

Answer (score -1):

https://i.stack.imgur.com/2qfhd.jpg

That error is raising because of the event propagation caused from the child. Just prevent it.
That error is raising because of the event propagation caused from the child. Just prevent it.
That error is raising because of the event propagation caused from the child. Just prevent it.