# jQuery stop event bubbling on input blur method?

Tags: jquery, events, input, event-bubbling, stoppropagation

I'm having a problem with jQuery and hoping for your help.
I've been searching for a long time for a solution, but came up with nothing.

I have a input field, and when I click (focus) on it, some div, with a specific ID appears in DOM, and when I click somewhere else ( blur ), that div hides.

What i need to do, is when i click on that specific div, to stay it visible and not hide.

So how can I do that?

Thank you and sorry for my bad english.

```
$(function(){

    $('input').focus(function() {
        $('#visible-block').show();
    });

    $('input').blur(function() {
        $('#visible-block').hide();
    });

});
```

I have a little demo for that: http://jsfiddle.net/uJ8nW/

Comment: simple workaround: http://jsfiddle.net/uJ8nW/6/

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11173509/jquery-blur-should-not-fire-if-div-is-clicked-focused

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply check if your are hover the div when losing focus on your input before hiding it:

```
$('input').blur(function() {
    if(!$('#visible-block').is(":hover"))
        $('#visible-block').hide();
});
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uJ8nW/9/)

Edit:
After reading the comments, here is the new solution without the need for the blur function:

```
$(function(){

    $('input').focus(function() {
        $('#visible-block').show();
    });

    $('#visible-block').blur(function() {
         $('#visible-block').hide();
    });

    $('html').click(function() {
        //Hide the menus if visible
        $('#visible-block').hide();
    });

     $('input').click(function(event){
        event.stopPropagation();
    });

    $('#visible-block').click(function(event){
        event.stopPropagation();
    });

});
```

Here is the update [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uJ8nW/10/)

Comment: this wont work if the user clicks the div and then clicks elsewhere

Comment: Right, and assuming the green box is some kind of drop down menu, you also want a `blur` handler for the green box.

Comment: It wasn't part of the question but I have edited my answer to fit your needs, @zozo answer is not bad too

Answer (score 0):

Maybe not the best solution, but might fit your needs.

```
$(function(){

$('input').focus(function() {
    $('#visible-block').show();
});

$('input').blur(function() {
    if (!$('#visible-block').is(":hover"))
        $('#visible-block').hide();
}); 

$('#wrapper').click(function() {
    if (!$('#visible-block').is(":hover") && !$('input').is(":hover"))
        $('#visible-block').hide();
}); 
});
```